# When I publish my LightSwitch app to Azure staging, the production deployment stops

Tags: deployment, azure, production, staging

Every time I publish my app to staging (from the LightSwitch publishing wizard in Visual Studio 2010) my production deployment stops.  I can then restart the production deployment, but this is obviously not what I want.

Both the staging and production deployments share the same storage and SQL Azure database.

Any ideas would be apprecicated.

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1):

This is not a normal behavior.  I suggest you contact Azure support.  In general, Azure deployments are isolated from one another.

Potential thought: when you say Production deployment stops, do you mean the instances are actually entering "Stopped" state or is it simply not working?  If the latter, perhaps you're using AppFabric Cache and are running out of connections when second deployment is brought online?